# Is $\frac{ab}{dc}<1$ if $0<a<c<d<b$ and $a+b<c+d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I'm trying to prove $\frac{ab}{dc}<1$ if $0<a<c<d<b$ and $a+b<c+d$. I've played around with this a bit and I'm pretty confident its true.

My approach is to use AMGM

Want to show:
$$\frac{ab}{cd}<1$$
$$\iff \sqrt{ab}<\sqrt{cd}$$
but $$\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}{2}<\frac{c+d}{2}$$
If I could show $\frac{a+b}{2}<\sqrt{cd}$ I would be sorted, but I'm not sure if this stronger condition is true. At this point I haven't use the fact $a<c<d<b$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that

$$
a + b < c + d
$$
$$
(a + b)^2 < (c + d)^2 \tag1.
$$

Next, from $0 < a < c < d < b$ we have

$$
b - a > d - c
$$
$$
(b - a)^2 > (d - c)^2\tag2.
$$

Subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$ to get

$$
(a + b)^2 - (b - a)^2 < (c + d)^2 - (d - c)^2\\
4ab < 4cd \\
\frac{ab}{cd} < 1.
$$

Comment: Nicely done, do you know if this inequality has a name or source?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not aware of any name for this inequality.